# Why Arabic string change the strings tags in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, localization, multiple-languages

When i copy the Arabic word in string tags after that automatically change the string tag slash.e.g. In English folder(values-en_US) its

```
    <string name="dining">Dining/string>
```

when i paste this same tag in values-ar_AE folder and replace the Dinning with Arabic word الطعام. e.g it show me like that

```
   <string name="dining"/>الطعا م<string>
```

and when i click on this string tag and try to set like e.g

```
   <string name="dining">الطعا م</string>
```

its automatically change the sequence of tag on press space key to write further more word in same string tag, change every thing inside tag. I think its some thing auto that only support the left to right language not right to left.
Please help me how to fix this issue